# How to run a custom command unique to a PR on merging a PR?

Tags: github, pull-request, data-migration

I am wondering if there is any way to do the following. Say I have an "open data" repo, which allows people to submit content. The repo saves all the data, and the changes to the structured JSON/YAML is reviewed in a PR. But then because I am in a serverless system (like Vercel), I need to upload the changes to the data to the production database, on merge of the branch. So there should be required a custom data migration in the PR, which runs when the PR is approved and merged.

How can that be accomplished? All I can imagine as a solution is having a special "code block" in markdown with some JSON config explaining what script to run for the data migration, and you add that marked code snippet as a comment to the PR, then parse the PR comments and figure out what script to run from that. But that would be of course (seemingly) a super hack, so is there a right way to do something like this?

The other option is to have to run the script/command manually after you merge the PR, but ideally there would be a more automatic way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub itself can run code on various events through [actions](https://github.com/features/actions). Actions are configured through YAML files in the directory [`.github/workflows`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/understanding-github-actions#create-an-example-workflow) in the repository. Some actions relative to a branch use the workflow files from that branch, while “global” actions use the workflow files from the default branch (typically called `main`, or `master` for older repositories).

For example, this workflow runs `bin/update-production-database` whenever the `main` branch is updated (whether from a pull request merge or by pushing directly):

```
name: Update database
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  update-database:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: bin/update-production-database
```

See more examples in [Deploying with GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/about-deployments/deploying-with-github-actions). To pass the credentials needed to access the database, set up an [encrypted secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets).

To only run the job on a PR merge and not on other pushes, see [Running your workflow when a pull request merges](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-workflow-when-a-pull-request-merges).

If you use Vercel (which I know nothing about), it claims it [“automatically deploys your GitHub projects”](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/git/vercel-for-github) so there may be a built-in solution there (either using actions so that the trigger comes from GitHub, or using some Vercel-owned server which polls GitHub).